# How to not include macOS sys header files in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos

I created a simple project with only one file `main.c` as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct dirent{
    short inum;
    char name[14];
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It couldn't build because of error `Type 'struct dirent' has incompatible definitions in different translation units`. I found it has conflicts with the `sys/dirent.h` even though I didn't include it.

How can I tell Xcode to not to include `sys/dirent.h`, and let me define my own `struct dirent`?